# Refreshing PivotTables

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen a multitude of questions on the net about using VBA to refresh PivotTables.  Most suggest code like this:

```
Sub RefreshPivotTables()
    Dim pivotTable As PivotTable
    For Each pivotTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pivotTable.RefreshTable
    Next
End Sub
```

While this kind of answer might give the expected result, it might do so at a terrible cost.

I have a large worksheet; 11 columns by 771427 rows.  The entire worksheet is then defined as the source data to three PivotTables per column in each of three further worksheets (they perform different kinds of analysis).  I have around 199 PivotTables in all.

If I use the ‘Refresh All’ button in the Data menu, then the update process takes many, many hours.  With no progress report to explain the reason why, or to confirm Excel had not hung, I resorted to constructing VBA code to first list the PivotTables in a new worksheet and then, one by one, refresh the nominated PivotTable.  By updating the listing as it goes, I can now see the progress being made.

However I recently stumbled on a change in the dataset that caused me to manually refresh just one of my PivotTables and to my horror all of the Pivot Tables were updated – in minutes and not in hours.

Further testing with the VBA code to skip the `.RefreshTable` method if the PivotTable and Worksheet names were not the one I wanted to update (***see below***), led me to believe that the `.RefreshTable` method is updating all PivotTables – either all in that worksheet, all in the workbook, or perhaps just all that share the same source data.  Furthermore I believe Microsoft have the same issue when you press the ‘Refresh All’ button.

```
Sub RefreshPivotTables()
    Dim Pt As PivotTable
    Dim St As Worksheet
    For Each St In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In St.PivotTables
            If pt.Name = "PivotTable151" And St.Name = "Sheet3" Then
                Set pvtTable = pt.TableRange1.PivotTable
                pvtTable.RefreshTable
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I am using Excel 2010.  So what’s going on here?  How can the above answer be improved to save on repeated refreshes?

Comment: One alternative can be write a small macro and instruct it to refresh only those pivot which you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something too but you are telling it

```
For Each pivotTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
```

so of course it is going to refresh them all that are connected to that sheet.

Can we see the code you played around with to not update the specific files?

Also have you tried:

`Sheets("SHEET_NAME").PivotTables("PIVOT_TABLE_NAME").PivotCache.Refresh`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222091/refresh-both-the-external-data-source-and-pivot-tables-together-within-a-time-sc)

Comment: One would expect the `For Each` to refresh each table one at a time, not all of them within every loop iteration.  And you suggest `.PivotCache.Refresh` - why?

Comment: I've now added the table skipping code to original question.  This still updates all of the tables though.

Comment: I'll try to see if I can work on it some today depending on my workload.  It might be how Excel handles the refresh; not sure. As Nelly mentioned above might try a small macro.  I'll update you soon as I can.