# VBA macro to refresh workbook not working

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to do 'Refresh All' (as shown in the image below) using a Macro:

[image]

Following is the macro (which is written in Module1):

```
Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
  ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

And then I'm writing a VBScript as follows:

```
'Code should be placed in a .vbs file
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("excel.xlsm", , True)

WScript.Echo "Executing RefreshAll"
objExcel.Application.Run "'excel.xlsm'!Module1.Workbook_RefreshAll"

WScript.Echo "Executing Mailing"
objExcel.Application.Run "'excel.xlsm'!ThisWorkbook.Mail"

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

But it is not refreshing the workbook.

Comment: Is the macro not invoked, or does it not refresh the workbook you want? Add some debug output to `Workbook_RefreshAll` (e.g. `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name`).

Comment: So, even when I manually run the macro the file doesn't get refreshed.

Comment: Did you put the command I suggested into the macro? Does it output the name of the workbook you want to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You have some mismatching of your objects and parameters of the run.

Instead of `objExcel.Application.Run "'excel.xlsm'!Module1.Workbook_RefreshAll"` you should be using your `book` object that you created and in the run parameter you do not need to call the workbook name again. I.E. `book.Application.Run "Module1.Workbook_RefreshAll"`

Also you may want to look in to how you are creating that `book` object. Presumable if the vbs file and xlsm file are in the folder that *should* work. But it doesn't always.

You may want to consider adding this to the beginning of your script

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

Then modify your script to

```
 Set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Open( curDir & "\excel.xlsm" )
```

Comment: But even when I run the macro for refreshing (i.e., in Module 1), it still does not refresh.

Comment: It may have to do with background refresh setting on the connections. Try either disabling it manually or modify your refresh code like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18836346/3658485. See if that helps